# Compare hash values with String

Tags: ruby

I want to compare values from hash and Sting.

```
successful_response = {
  '00' => { error_message: 'TESTMODE: No real money will be transferred!'}
}

if error = successful_response[response_code]
  if successful_response[response_code] != current_technical_message
    raise "\n\nWrong tecnical message for code #{response_code}. It should be #{successful_response[response_code]}"
  end
else
  UnknownResponseError.new(technical_message, response_code)
end
```

Every time I error. Looks like this is not the proper way to compare the values successful_response[response_code] and current_technical_message

When I print the values I get 
`{:error_message=>"TESTMODE: No real money will be transferred!"}` and

```
TESTMODE: No real money will be transferred!
```

What is the proper way to compare them?

Comment: The proper way is to compare comparable things. String to a string. Or hash to a hash.

Comment: What is the proper way to extract the String from the Hash?

Comment: `Hash#[]` method, of course. Which you use already.

Comment: Ok, but why I get this result?

Comment: Because you're not using enough of it.

Comment: Can you show me complete working example please?

Comment: I can, but that would be giving you a fish.

Comment: My I know why I receive down vote?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Given SO is a Q&A site, coming here to be given the fish and not taught how to fish seems perfectly reasonable, doesn't it?

Comment: @MichaelKohl: yep, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `successful_response[response_code]` points at another hash. The easiest — but potentially error-prone — way to fix your problem is to use the following:

```
successful_response[response_code][:error_message]
```

If you Ruby version is new enough, [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-dig) is a good alternative:

```
successful_response.dig(response_code, :error_message)
```